# In which Block was Len Sassaman memorialised?

Tags: transactions, script, encoding, message

It has been mentioned a couple times here and there that [Len Sassaman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Len_Sassaman) was memorialised somewhere in the Block Chain. I was able to find a dump of of the [tribute to him](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=BUB3dygQ), but I can't seem to find where in the Chain did this tribute come from.

What are the Blocks/Transactions that contain the tribute to Len Sassaman?

Comment: Not sure about the block chain. Len was brilliant but he was still a bitcoin skeptic. I had this conversation with him about one week before his death. http://themonetaryfuture.blogspot.com.es/2011/07/len-sassaman-on-bitcoin.html

Comment: Related notes from Dan Kaminsky, the one who created the tribute: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=34458.0  and another thread discussing it: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=33618.0

Comment: @matonis doesn't that show he was skeptical it could remain anonymous, not of the entire concept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Block [138725](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/138725)

Transaction [930a2114cdaa86e1fac46d15c74e81c09eee1d4150ff9d48e76cb0697d8e1d72](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/930a2114cdaa86e1fac46d15c74e81c09eee1d4150ff9d48e76cb0697d8e1d72)

Answer (score 2):

[930a2114cdaa86e1fac46d15c74e81c09eee1d4150ff9d48e76cb0697d8e1d72](http://blockexplorer.com/tx/930a2114cdaa86e1fac46d15c74e81c09eee1d4150ff9d48e76cb0697d8e1d72)
as reported by forum user makomk [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=33618.msg420597#msg420597).

Answer (score 2):

**Find it yourself with my preprocessed ASCII strings data**

At https://github.com/cirosantilli/bitcoin-strings-with-txids I have uploaded a dump of all ASCII strings of length 20 or greater, including scripts to generate that data from a local copy of the blockchain by using https://github.com/alecalve/python-bitcoin-blockchain-parser

The main difference between my dump and https://bitcoinstrings.com/blk00003.txt is that since I parse the blockchain, I am dumping a bit more metadata, notably the transaction IDs.

So if you do:

```
git clone https://github.com/cirosantilli/bitcoin-strings-with-txids
cd bitcoin-strings-with-txids
git grep 'BEGIN TRIBUTE'
```

one of the very few hits will be:

```
data/out/0138.txt:2:---BEGIN TRIBUTE--- #./BitLen ...
```

and then when you open the corresponding file [data/out/0138.txt#L2](https://github.com/cirosantilli/bitcoin-strings-with-txids/blob/master/data/out/0138.txt#L2) you see:

```
tx 930a2114cdaa86e1fac46d15c74e81c09eee1d4150ff9d48e76cb0697d8e1d72
---BEGIN TRIBUTE--- #./BitLen ...
```

Unfortunately my dump does not do automatic newline splitting at the end of every ASCII payload, so this particular ASCII art does not show up correctly.

Before `OP_RETURN`, payloads were always put into a 20 bytes long address, and this particular ASCII art was intended to have automatic newlines.

However, this prevents ASCII art with lines longer than 20 bytes, with explicit `\n` added, and so I decided to not automatically add newlines as it allows seeing many more interesting ASCII arts correctly on average.  I did an overview of the most interesting ASCII arts I've found on [this blog post](https://cirosantilli.com/cool-data-embedded-in-the-bitcoin-blockchain/ascii-art).

**Manually obtaining and interpreting data from an online blockchain tracker API**

Here's are links that still works as of 2021 and have full disassembled data:

- https://blockchain.info/tx/930a2114cdaa86e1fac46d15c74e81c09eee1d4150ff9d48e76cb0697d8e1d72?format=json
- https://blockchain.info/block-height/138725?format=json

based on [this other answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/3384/21282).

The key contents are the outputs of the transaction:

```
   "out":[
      {
         "spent":false,
         "tx_index":0,
         "type":0,
         "addr":"1CqKQ2EqUscMkeYRFMmgepNGtfKynXzKW7",
         "value":1000000,
         "n":0,
         "script":"76a91481ccb4ee682bc1da3bda70176b7ccc616a6ba9da88ac"
      },
      {
         "spent":false,
         "tx_index":0,
         "type":0,
         "addr":"157sXa7duStAvq3dPLWe7J449sgh47eHzw",
         "value":1000000,
         "n":1,
         "script":"76a9142d2d2d424547494e20545249425554452d2d2d2088ac"
      },
...
      {
         "spent":false,
         "tx_index":0,
         "type":0,
         "addr":"157sXYpjvAyEJ6TdVFaVzmoETAQnHB6FGU",
         "value":1000000,
         "n":77,
         "script":"76a9142d2d2d2d454e4420545249425554452d2d2d2d2088ac"
      }
```

where:

```
echo 76a9142d2d2d424547494e20545249425554452d2d2d2088ac | xxd -r -p
echo 76a9142d2d2d2d454e4420545249425554452d2d2d2d2088ac | xxd -r -p
```

give:

```
v---BEGIN TRIBUTE---
v----END TRIBUTE----
```

which clarifies how the message is encoded in the `script` entries of each output. They are not therefore actually contiguous in the stream.

This is why if you download the blockchain and do:

```
strings -n20 .bitcoin/blocks/blk00003.dat
```

it works really well to see the data, as the newlines come from `strings` itself. The `strings` output can also be seen at: https://bitcoinstrings.com/blk00003.txt

**Announcement speech by Dan Kaminsky at BlackHat 2011**

Doesn't give the tx, but people who come here might want to see it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLIYq3ePaX4&t=502s